# socket.on event not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

```
let tick = (z)=>{
tokens[z].l.soilders.spearman.state+=0.75
tokens[z].l.soilders.swordman.state+=0.50
tokens[z].l.soilders.archer.state+=0.25
tokens[z].l.soilders.halberdier.state+=0.30

tokens[z].r.soilders.spearman.state+=0.75
tokens[z].r.soilders.swordman.state+=0.50
tokens[z].r.soilders.axeman.state+=0.20
tokens[z].r.soilders.halberdier.state+=0.25

io.emit("res",{
    err:false,
    errno:false,
    op:"start",
    data:tokens[z]
})

console.log("ticked, data sending");}
```

this function recalls with something like setInterval and gives me a lot console.log("ticked, data sending") output
so, io.emit is working

but, after once receive, client is don't receive is data sended by io.emit

below is the client code

normally it should log the 8th line from the bottom or 2nd line

but log once times

and the server keeps sending

no error in console

```
socket.on("res",e=>{
console.log("data received",e);
if(e.err){
    switch(e.errno){
        case 1:{
            alert("geçersiz turnuva jetonu")
        }break
        case 2:{
            alert("azami oyuncu sayısı")
        }break
        case 3:{
            alert("aynı oyuncu")
        }break
        case 4:{
            alert("oyuncu bulunamadı")
            document.getElementById("ready").disabled=false
        }break
        case 5:{
            alert("zaten hazırsın")
        }break
        case 6:{
            alert("geçersiz müdahale")
            document.getElementById("ready").disabled=false
        }break

        default:{
            console.log("bilinmeyen hata kodu");
        }
    }
}else{
    switch(e.op){
        case "init":{

            right = Object.keys(e.data.r.soilders)
            left = Object.keys(e.data.l.soilders)

            for(let i=1;i<=right.length;i++){
                div1 = document.createElement("div")
                canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
                div1.setAttribute("style",`box-sizing: border-box;
                height: 100%;
                float: ${"right"};
                aspect-ratio: 1/1;
                margin-right: -2%;`)
                canvas.setAttribute("style",`aspect-ratio: 1/1;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;`)
                canvas.setAttribute("id","rsoilders"+i)
                canvas.setAttribute("width","100%")
                canvas.setAttribute("height","100%")

                div1.appendChild(canvas)

                document.getElementById("right").appendChild(div1)
            }

            for(let i=1;i<=left.length;i++){
                div1 = document.createElement("div")
                canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
                div1.setAttribute("style",`box-sizing: border-box;
                height: 100%;
                float: ${"left"};
                aspect-ratio: 1/1;
                margin-right: -2%;`)
                canvas.setAttribute("style",`aspect-ratio: 1/1;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;`)
                canvas.setAttribute("id","lsoilders"+i)
                canvas.setAttribute("width","100%")
                canvas.setAttribute("height","100%")

                div1.appendChild(canvas)

                document.getElementById("left").appendChild(div1)
            }



            if(e.data.l.clientId==socket.id){
                //add mouse events
            }else if(e.data.r.clientId==socket.id){
                //add mouse events
            }
        }break
        case "start":{
            console.log(e,"x");
        }break
        default:{
            alert("server crash")
        }
    }
}
```

})

Comment: you need to show where tick is being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server was in a bottleneck because I ran  run() every 5 second inside  while(true) and the server was unable to send or receive data

```
let run = (t)=>{
tok=t
console.log("in run func");
let last = new Date().getTime()
,now
,delta = 0
while(true){
    now = new Date().getTime()
    delta += (now - last) / f
    last = now
    while(delta >= 5*fps){
        tick(tok)
        console.log("tick called");
        delta -= 5*fps
    }
}}
```

while(true) was needed because tick event setInterval etc. not healthy with

[reason](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/)

to solve I moved my while(true) loop to a different file using {fork} = require("child_process") and it worked in a different process